# How use password protection without database

Tags: php, authentication

I have this code running to protect my site, but I would like to know how I could use multiple users without a database.
I read that you can do with a text file but do not know how, my notions of PHP are minimal.

thanks for the help.

```
<?php

session_start();

$username = "test";
$password = "test";

if(isset($_GET['logout']))
{
  unset($_SESSION["login"]);
  echo "You have logout ... ";
  echo "[<a href='" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "'>Login</a>]";
  exit;
}

if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) || !isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']) ||      !isset($_SESSION["login"]))
{
  header("WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=\"Ghost SMS\"");
  header("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized");
  $_SESSION["login"] = true;
  echo "You are unauthorized ... ";
  echo "[<a href='" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "'>Login</a>]";
  exit;
}
else
{
  if($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] == $username && $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] == $password)
  {
    echo "Welcome ";
    echo "[<a href='" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?logout'>Logout</a>]";
  }
  else
  {
    unset($_SESSION["login"]);
    header("Location: " . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
  }
}

// content here

?>
```

Comment: Could you explain the term "more of a user"? ie what additional functionality do you need?

Comment: I mean I can use multiple users

Comment: You are already saving all your data in $session variable which is different for different users

Comment: @knightrider: But he can't authenticate users based on the SESSION data alone.

Comment: @user1591751: Why would you want this? What's wrong with using a database, I can assure you, it's superior to a text file any day of the week.

Comment: @user1591751 missed that. As others pointed out it is better to use database in this scenario.

Comment: as I said before my PHP skills are not many. then I thought it would be easier not to use a database, anyway accept suggestions for the use of a database

Comment: @knightrider: the headers he is sending trigger the HTTP auth password dialog in the browser - he is using that to authenticate because the browser can store the passwords and log you in automatically when you come back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$users = array('user' => 'password',
               'user2' => 'pass',
               'user3' => 'pass',
              );
```

Then change this line

```
if($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] == $username && $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] == $password)
```

to this

```
if (isset($users[$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']]) // user exists
    && ($users[$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']] == $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']) // password matches
   )
```

Also - if the password fails you need to spit out the headers again (instead of doing a location redirect) - Otherwise the user will never be prompted to enter the correct password if he makes a mistake (entering an invalid user/password will cause a redirect loop)